# Control cursor with c++ and x11

Tags: cursor, x11, position

What x11 header file and function would I use to change the position of the cursor on the display? I have heard there is a straight forward function on Vc++ but I wish to be able to use this on linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't trivially port programs from windows to xwindows, at least not without using a cross platform toolkit like gtk+ or Qt.

That said, the most basic way to move the pointer about on X is using the `XWarpPointer()` method, which is to be had by including `X11/Xlib.h`

EDIT:

Apparently you are using Qt after all.  you need to use [`QCursor::setpos`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qcursor.html#setPos) which is defined in `QCursor`

Comment: Ok, thank you. How would you port those to another platform? Only reason for asking is because this is being written in qt and it might save me some time.